# I want to access a bucket with a long name (> 63 chars) using AWS APIs for C++

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk

I want to access a bucket with a long name (> 63 chars) using AWS APIs for C++. I know that AWS S3 mandates that the bucket names must be 3 to 63 chars long. Any names less than 3 characters or greater than 63 characters are not allowed. However AWS SDK can be used to access and work with buckets and objects object storage from other vendors which have no limitation on the bucket name size. Can anyone please help.

I looked into AWS SDK and APIs documentation.
Expecting example code.

Comment: The following rules apply for naming buckets in Amazon S3: Bucket names must be between 3 (min) and 63 (max) characters long. Why would you expect to find a SDK  code example that breaches naming rules?

Answer (score 0):

I find it hard to believe that any vendor would allow you to create bucket names that are longer than 63 characters.

However, if there are other vendors who somehow allow you to circumvent the AWS naming rules, they should also provide methods to access those buckets.

The AWS SDK for C++ won’t allow you to create or access those buckets with non-conforming names.